# How to plot geom_point with alpha (transparency) increasing as the level of factors increasing (or simpler, just put the higher level into the back)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

How to plot geom_point with alpha (transparency) increasing as the level of factors increasing (or simpler, just put the higher level into the back)? For instance, this plot doesn't allow the red to show up above the blue even though it's the first level of the factor.

[image]

The code that I'm using to make this plot is:

```
belplauPlot<-function(belplau_mat, xlab, color, y="rplau", x="index", levels=NULL, legend_title="", main_title="",is_log_scale=TRUE,is_negative=FALSE) {
  ggplot(as.data.frame(belplau_mat) %>% mutate(!!sym(y):=(if(is_log_scale) log(!!sym(y)) * (if(is_negative) -1 else 1) else !!sym(y))) %>% mutate(!!sym(x):=xlab)) +
    geom_point(aes(x=!!sym(x),y=!!sym(y),colour=factor(color, if (is.null(levels)) unique(color) else levels))) + 
    labs(title=main_title,color=legend_title) + theme_bw() + ylab(if (is_log_scale) paste0(if(is_negative) "-","log(",y,")") else y) 
}
```

and the example the I use to generate the plot is

```
bel_plau_plot <- belplauPlot(matrix(rep(1,101),ncol=1,dimnames=list(NULL,"rplau")), 1:101, c(rep(0,50),1,rep(0,50)), levels=c(1,0),is_log_scale=FALSE,is_negative = FALSE)
```

---

Following the first answer with slight modification of labels, the test gives the wrong y-scale because the logarithm and negativity aren't applied.

```
bel_plau_plot <- belplauPlot(matrix(rep(1,101),ncol=1,dimnames=list(NULL,"rplau")), 1:101, c(rep("B",50),"A",rep("B",50)), levels=c("A","B"),is_log_scale=TRUE,is_negative = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points are added in the order as they appear in your data. Hence, if you want to to put one level in the back or in the front you have to reorder your dataset. In the code below I convert to a `factor` using `reorder`. Then use `order` to order the dataset by `group` in descending order so that the smaller group appears last in the data for the second plot.

Using some fake example to illustrate the issue and the fix by reordering:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(1000),
  y = rnorm(1000),
  group = sample(c("A", "B"), 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.1, .9))
)

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, color = group)) +
  geom_point()

dat$group <- reorder(dat$group, rep(1, nrow(dat)), FUN = length)

p2 <- dat[order(dat$group, decreasing = TRUE), ] |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = group)) +
  geom_point()

library(patchwork)

p1 + p2
```

[image]

**EDIT** Based on the provided example data here is a refactored version of your code where I moved all data wrangling and preparation parts outside of `ggplot()` and finally added my code lines from above to order your data:

```r
belplauPlot <- function(belplau_mat,
                        xlab,
                        color,
                        y = "rplau", x = "index",
                        levels = NULL,
                        legend_title = "",
                        main_title = "",
                        is_log_scale = TRUE,
                        is_negative = FALSE) {
  if (is.null(levels)) levels <- unique(color)

  dat <- as.data.frame(belplau_mat) |>
    mutate(
      !!sym(x) := xlab,
      color = factor(color, levels = levels)
    )

  if (is_log_scale) {
    ylab <- paste0("log(", y, ")")
    .mult <- 1
    if (is_negative) {
      .mult <- -1
      ylab <- paste0("-", ylab)
    }
    dat <- mutate(
      dat, !!sym(y) := log(!!sym(y)) * .mult
    )
  } else {
    ylab <- y
  }

  dat$order <- reorder(dat$color, rep(1, nrow(dat)), FUN = length)
  
  dat <- dat[order(dat$order, decreasing = TRUE), ]
  
  ggplot(dat) +
    geom_point(
      aes(
        x = !!sym(x),
        y = !!sym(y),
        colour = color
      )
    ) +
    labs(
      title = main_title, color = legend_title,
      ylab = ylab
    ) +
    theme_bw()
}

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

belplauPlot(
  matrix(rep(1, 101),
    ncol = 1,
    dimnames = list(NULL, "rplau")
  ),
  xlab = 1:101,
  color = c(rep(0, 50), 1, rep(0, 50)),
  levels = c(1, 0),
  is_log_scale = FALSE,
  is_negative = FALSE
)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to modify my code to get such result? Should I modify color to not be an input but as a column?

Comment: Well, as a first step I would move all the data wrangling outside of the `ggplot()` call, i.e. `dat <- as.data.frame(belplau_mat) %>% ...` and `ggplot(dat, ...)` That will make your code much cleaner and easier to understand and allows for easier debugging. And the same for the conversion of `color` to a factor. After doing my code you could add my code as two more steps in the data wrangling pipeline.

Comment: ... for more help with your real code you have to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. As you see from my example it's not that difficult to create a fake example dataset. Then we can run your code and offer a solution more suited to your real data/code.

Comment: I've made a reproducible example

Comment: I was wondering if cbinding color to the matrix and then arrange by factor would be simpler?

Comment: It still doesn't work, Please see the update

Comment: Actually, there's a bug. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: See my edit for a refactored code where I added my pieces from above to reorder your data.

Comment: Thanks. Your version works. My version failed because I mixed character and numerics into the same matrix.

Comment: Actually, I think is_log_scale doesn't function as desired

Comment: Also is_negative isn't working.

Comment: I'm supposed to get log(rplau) or -log(rplau) as the y-axis labels when I take these two as true.

Comment: Even if I fix this the plot by removing `ylab` in labs and add `ylab(ylab) +` seems to give different answer than I had before

Comment: Maybe it's a problem of my initial code?

Comment: Actually, no, the logarithm didn't go through

Comment: Ok, changing `dat <- dat |> 
      mutate(
        !!sym(y) := log(!!sym(y)) * .mult
        )` does the job

Comment: Aw. Sorry. Of course do we have to assign back to `dat`. Will fix that in my answer too.